# mySQL vs. sqlite alias incompatible?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, alias

I use Yii framework with mySQL with an ORM. When I switch to sqlite, I suddenly get 'column not found' errors for columns that have aliases in their query:

```
Querying SQL: SELECT `privateAccesses`.`project_id` AS `t1_c0`, ... FROM `project` `privateAccesses`
```

Then I get:

```
CDbException: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: privateAccesses
```

So I think it has something to do with aliases.. anyone know if the mySQL/sqlite aliases are somehow incompatible? Idea how to fix this? Basic aliases seem to work in sqlite..

Thanks,
MrB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, it's something about the ORM omitting certain columns on sqlite for some reason..